# Django ORM: List of Foreign Key values

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a table which has a column which stores a list of values. These values are basically Foreign key values of another table.

Tables are:

```
groups (
  id               TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  users            TEXT [],
  name             TEXT NOT NULL,
  user_count       INT  NOT NULL,
  group_type       TEXT NOT NULL CHECK (group_type IN ('random', 'friends')) DEFAULT 'random',
  validity_period  INT  NOT NULL,
  user_add_time    INT  NOT NULL,
  winner           TEXT [],
  energy_drink_fee INT                                                       DEFAULT 0,
  energy_bar_fee   INT                                                       DEFAULT 0,
  winnings         INT                                                       DEFAULT 0, -- can be 0 (for free tournaments), 40, 150 (for paid tournaments)
  created_at       TIMESTAMP                                                 DEFAULT now(),
  updated_at       TIMESTAMP                                                 DEFAULT now()
);
```

In Django, it is:

```
class Groups(models.Model):
    id = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    users = ArrayField(blank=True, null=True, base_field=models.CharField)
    name = models.TextField()
    user_count = models.IntegerField()
    group_type = models.TextField()
    validity_period = models.IntegerField()
    user_add_time = models.IntegerField()
    winner = ArrayField(blank=True, null=True, base_field=models.CharField)
    energy_drink_fee = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    energy_bar_fee = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    winnings = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

'users' and 'winners' are the columns which store ids of User table (username is the id).

I am not changing the database, the tables are the same, except that I am using Django for reading into this database (Legacy DBs). I am still not sure about the ArrayField though.

This is the query I had written in SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(g.*) AS match_count, TEXT(g.created_at::DATE) AS created_at
FROM groups g
JOIN users u ON u.username = ANY (g.winner)
WHERE g.created_at::DATE >= '2018-01-01' AND g.created_at::DATE <= '2018-01-20'
      AND g.winnings = 0 AND g.group_type = 'random' AND u.type = 'u'
      AND g.winner IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY g.created_at::DATE
```

I need to migrate this query into Django's ORM.
How can I do a join with this array field (winner)?

Comment: can you add all related model classes to the question?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge, added the table

Comment: I mean your Django models, not `mysql / postgresql` table schema

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge I have added the Django model.

Comment: Just in case you are not aware, you can also perform raw sql queries from django, in case you don't absolutely need to use the ORM: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/

Comment: @Hoff I know this, but I would like to know how to do it in ORM. I have to use this kind of join in many places.

Comment: @AnkitaGupta Have a look at ArrayFields, and how to query them with 'contains': https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#contains

Comment: @Hoff If I just had to go through the docs, I wouldn't have asked a question here. I don't have a specific set of values that I need to fetch, I need to make a join with this Array field. `JOIN users u ON u.username = ANY (g.winner)' . I am unable to write this in ORM. Groups.objects.filter(created_at__date__gte=start_date, created_at__date__lte=end_date, winner__contains=user__username) is giving me an error. Write anything in place of 'user__username'.

Comment: @AnkitaGupta Please add what you have tried and what errors your are getting to your question body (this is good practice on stackoverflow)

Comment: @Hoff Please try to keep your sarcasm to yourself. I have specified what I have tried, (using arrayfield) and I am trying to find if this is the best way to go forward to change my Raw SQL to Django's ORM. Clearly, instead of helping out, you are more interested in teaching the Best Practices of StackOverFlow. I request you to not reply on this thread if you can't help me.

Comment: @AnkitaGupta apologies if my comment came across as sarcastic - it was not intended like that. The intent was to improve the quality of the question, so that even if I can't help you out, it will get more exposure and might be seen by someone who can.